# Display received data from .php script in ListView

Tags: php, android, json, http, android-listview

How to put data from database table in `listView` using Android code.

This is PHP code, I need Android code for this:

```
$your_querry="select * from member ";
$query=mysql_query($your_querry);
$list=array();
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $list[]=$row;
}

echo json_encode($list);
```

Comment: Um there are a lot of steps in this process. You need to (1) download that information from the sever using an AsyncTask (2) process the JSON that you get (3) create a list adapter that you load this information into - there are a lot of tutorials on how to set up list view on google you can find but there's too many steps to really give a good answer here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for this question use JSONParser.java and ListAdapter.java ,

if your listview contain image I strongly recommend to you use

```
1-MemoryCache.java.
2-FileCache.java.
3-ImageLoader.java.
4-Utils.java.
```

that's all I think

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
DefaultHttpClient   httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(new BasicHttpParams());
HttpGet httppost = new HttpGet("path/to/your/php-script");

httpGet.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

InputStream inputStream = null;
String result = null;
try {
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);           
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    inputStream = entity.getContent();

    // Now parse the JSON with some JSON library like Jackson, Gson or JSON.org
    ...
    // Then fill the listView with the objects you parsed
    ...
```